# How do I stop the DevOps REST API from wrapping an incoming JSON payload in double quotes?

Tags: json, rest, azure-devops, attachment, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to use the ADO REST API to attach files to work items. The problem seems to be that the incoming string is getting wrapped in double quotes at some point in the process. This can be seen in any attached .txt files (which open fine), and renders .png and .jpg files unable to be opened. The content I'm trying to attach is attachment "content bytes" pulled from Outlook via a connector in Oracle Integration Cloud, which I base 64 decode in OIC before sending to ADO.

This is the call I use to create the attachment in ADO (media type is application/json-patch+json):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0

"[]"
```

This is the response from that that I use to make the next call (media type is JSON):

```
{
  "id" : "",
  "url" : ""
}
```

This is the next call to then associate the attachment with a specific work item (media type is application/json-patch+json):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0

{
  "op" : "add",
  "path" : "/relations/-",
  "value" : {
    "rel" : "AttachedFile",
    "url" : ""
  }
}
```

Is there an html header or something I can use to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your txt file displaying binary content or the content of the file itself?

Comment: It displays a base 64 encoded string (in the form "dGVzdCB0ZXN0IHRlc3Q=" for instance, with the added quotes) unless I decode it first in OIC. If I decode it it displays the file's text content normally with the exception of the added quotes and added \r\n wherever a line break was present originally (in the form "test\r\ntest\r\ntest" for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo, it turns out Microsoft's docs are somewhat misleading and suggest that ADO is expecting a JSON payload for attachment creation when it is actually expecting just binary content. Once I found that out I used the function "decodeBase64ToReference" in OIC on the "contentBytes" from outlook. I then reconfigured my OIC connector to send a binary payload and mapped everything accordingly. Worked like a charm.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/92tPs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSKnt.png